# Hide SmartGwt ComboboxItem if it has only one value to be selected

Tags: combobox, smartgwt

I am working with SmartGwt.

Is it possible to hide the combobox dropdown button if it has only one Item?

Answer (score 3):

use the property like `setShowPickerIcon(false)`, If we use this property, the SelectPicker Icon mean dropdown button will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Add a change listener to it, if it has only one element, call `setVisible(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, it is not possible, but you can replace it with TextItem which has no dropdown button dynamically. Either by invoking setVisible(false/true) or by removing/adding it from/to the form.